# Как сделать так, чтобы выполнялись оба rewriterule?

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^post/(^[0-9]+)/$ file.php?id$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/edite/(.*)/$ file_edite.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Как сделать, чтобы оба правила работали?

Хоть в первом правиле и написано, что после первого слеша могут быть только цифры и ссылка заканчивается после регулярки, но это правило все равно мешает второму правилу.

Answer (score 2):

В первом правиле у вас ошибка

> ^post/(**^**[0-9]+)/$

У вас тут два раза начало строки отмечено перед `post` и в начале первой группы. Правильно будет так:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)/$ file.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/edite/(.+)/$ file_edite.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы второе правило не сделать более конкретным?

```
RewriteRule ^edite/(.*)/$ file_edite.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Можно и так. Но все равно интересно, можно ли сделать, чтобы работали оба правила как указано.

Answer (score 0):

обратите внимание на `[L]` — буква `L` здесь означает «last» («последнее»), т.е., **если** данное правило «сработает», то ни одно последующее уже не будет анализироваться.

уберите `[L]` из первой строки и, даже если это правило «сработает», второе всё равно будет проанализировано и, если оно удовлетворит условиям проверки, то выполнится и оно.